# Python, Django - Accessing Environment Variables in settings.py

Tags: python, django

Within my project, I want to send an email with python/Django. In order to do this, I need to specify multiple settings, and one of them is the password for my email. I want to retreive this from an environment variable.

When I reference the environment variable in settings.py, I get a message implying the value is wrong and not my actual password. I ensured that the environment variable is set to my actual password within bash_profile, and when I hardcoded my password in the settings file, the email is sent successfully.

This implies the issue is occurring when trying to retrieve the password as an environment variable.

**SETTINGS.py**:

```
import os
# me trying to retrieve password
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('email_password')
```

Anybody know the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> I ensured that the environment variable is set to my actual password within bash_profile

If you are following best practices and running Django in a virtual environment, it has a different set of environment variables. I suspect if you changed your setting to `os.environ['email_password']` you would get a `KeyError`, because that environment variable is not set.

There are a number of ways to export environment variables, but just to prove to yourself that this is the problem, export the value right in the command line with your virtual environment enabled, then run your project and try sending the email.

**Edit**

Since you're using pipenv, you can simply add a .env file in the root of your project, and pipenv will automatically set those environment variables for you when you activate the virtual environment.

**.env**

```
SECRET_KEY=asolidsecretkey
email_password=somesecurepassword
...
```

Comment: I am using a virtual environment(pipenv)

Comment: The method worked! When typing it in command line, the email got sent.

Comment: But how do I set this environ var permanently instead of having to enter in the command line?

Comment: Can you supply at least one method of doing this with Django?

Comment: Thanks mate. But when I use os.environ['email_password'] it also works perfectly. No key error. Is it ok for me to use this method instead?

Comment: You can use it, but know it will crash your app if you haven't set this environment variable (that's probably what you want in this case).

Comment: One question. Can you access your bash profile env vars in the .env file? by using os.environ.get?

Comment: No. It's just a text file. Also, make sure you add `.env` to your `.gitignore` so you don't add sensitive info to your repository. It's helpful to have a `.env.example` file with all the necessary env vars but with dummy values, and check that into version control.